# Not able to calculate no of div if dynamically created upon call of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating the below html dynamically inside ajax call and the html is successfully generated in browser like this:

```js
$("#rooms-information").ready(function() {
  $("#rooms-information .panel-default .panel-body").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var countButton = $("#" + id + " .button").length;
    if (countButton == 0) {
      $("#" + id).append("<p>Empty</p>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="rooms-information">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div id="rooms-information1" class="panel-body">
        <div class="buttons col-md-4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div id="rooms-information2" class="panel-body">
        <div class="buttons col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons col-md-4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div id="rooms-information3" class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript code is for checking if `div.panel-body` contains children `div.buttons` then do nothing and if `div.panel-body` does not contain any children `div.buttons` then append `p` tag.

The above code does not append `p` tag to such `div`.
Please note that the above html is generated upon the call of ajax function.
The above code does not throw any error in console.

Comment: in a fiddle test, eveything is working. Can you check if the `rooms-information` is loaded ? or just `console.log(id)` to see if you get something ? maybe you should change `ready` to `on load` https://jsfiddle.net/q2yrqotg/

Comment: I'm guessing you want `$("#" + id + " .buttons").length;`, with `.buttons` instead of `.button`. My version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/go1hxbpv/

Comment: @MihaiT it is not getting triggered so it does not display id in console

Comment: did you try `on load` instead of `ready` ?

Comment: outside the general document ready function and the code was exactly the same as above

Comment: to be clear, `$("#rooms-information .panel-default .panel-body").each(...)` should be done inside your ajax callback after you appended the html in document. `$("#rooms-information").ready()` is meaningless and won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but you just have a minor mistake. Instead of checking if class `.buttons` exists you check class `.button`.

Here I also changed one thing. In jQuery [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) loop you do not have to acces an element by id, because you loop through those elements. So in order to refer to current element you can just use `this`.

```js
$("#rooms-information").ready(function() {
  $("#rooms-information .panel-default .panel-body").each(function() {
    var $body = $(this);
    var countButton = $body.find(".buttons").length;
    if (countButton == 0) {
      $body.append("<p>Empty</p>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="rooms-information">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div id="rooms-information1" class="panel-body">
        <div class="buttons col-md-4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div id="rooms-information2" class="panel-body">
        <div class="buttons col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons col-md-4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div id="rooms-information3" class="panel-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

@NidaAmin I attach screenshot to show you taht it appends only to `div` without `.buttons` inside.

[image: screenshot]

So it is hard for me to find the problem when I don't have any :)
But I'll try anyway.

Try replacing this `$("#rooms-information").ready(function() {` with `$(window).on('load', function() {`

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $("#rooms-information .panel-default .panel-body").each(function() {
    var $body = $(this);
    var countButton = $body.find(".buttons").length;
    if (countButton == 0) {
      $body.append("<p>Empty</p>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="rooms-information">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div id="rooms-information1" class="panel-body">
        <div class="buttons col-md-4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div id="rooms-information2" class="panel-body">
        <div class="buttons col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons col-md-4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div id="rooms-information3" class="panel-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the above code and tried to debug it in console and noticed that the above code is triggered before loading of the html elements

Comment: @NidaAmin I don't know what you mean by that, but it works properly.If you want it to happen after ajax just add this code to ajax `success` callback function.

Comment: it is appending p tag to all the divs after adding inside success call

Comment: @NidaAmin what jquery version are you using?